# Are there any publicly available real-time data stream containing measurements outside Earth?

Tags: data-transmission, scientific-data, public-involvement

Analyzing data coming from outside Earth (such as the temperature around Curiosity on Mars, or the radiation level on geosynchronous orbit around Earth, etc.) might be an interesting task and/or hobby for those not working in the space industry.

Do NASA, ESA or any other organizations that owns devices outside Earth (= in space or on the surface of other bodies) provide public access to any real-time data stream to analyze anc such?

Comment: There's loads, what specifically are you after? Mind, "real-time" gets a bit ambiguous with minutes of light travel time, upload time slot allocation and such, but many are still close enough (usually referred to as "near real-time"). Try NASA's [Planetary Data System](https://pds.jpl.nasa.gov/) (there's various "nodes" too), or pages of individual missions, like e.g. [SDO](http://sdo.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/), [SOHO](http://sohowww.nascom.nasa.gov/data/realtime/), [MSL raw images](https://d2cj35nmzi9erd.cloudfront.net/msl/multimedia/raw/), [Cassini](http://saturn.jpl.nasa.gov/photos/raw/),...

Comment: @TildalWave By real-time, I mean that data is sent immediately after recording, but minutes or days later. You're right: receiving is a different question.

Comment: Some scientific data will be subject to embargo for various reasons, e.g. to ensure release quality, to protect intellectual property rights or other interests of involved parties,... But there's plenty to do if you're an enthusiast and would like to process data on your own as soon as it comes it. Of course, there might be slight delay to publish raw data, derivative "data products" will take longer to process, and some data simply doesn't come in as a continuous stream, but a lot of it is still "near real time". ESA tends to enforce stricter access restrictions than NASA, so it also depends.

Comment: When searching for some [realtime photos](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/how-many-photographs-are-there-of-the-whole-earth/6162#6162) of Earth from space I've stumbled upon tons upon tons of realtime measurement data coming in from meteorological satellites.